# Why is my SSIS configuration update not being saved?

Tags: configuration, scheduled-task, ssis

*I asked this over on SO with little success. I was wondering if any SF folks had some insight...*

I have a SSIS 2005 package that is up and running in our production environment. The package uses an SMTP Connection Manager to send an e-mail message out to a designated user. We have a scheduled job that executes this package, and also overrides the SMTP connection string so that the package can target the test or production mail server, which makes it possible to keep a single service on both our test and production servers, just configured differently.

We recently changed the server name of our production mail server and went into the scheduled job and changed the command prompt values that run to point to the new server. However, the next morning the job failed and the error log indicated that the job tried to connect to the old mail server.

Is there something I'm missing to updating the SSIS package parameters? Do I have to delete the existing package, and then reimport and reschedule the job again in order for the new server change to hold?

Comment: Can you post the cmd line that your job is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart the SQL Server Agent.  I've run into problems similar to this and that has fixed my problem.

Comment: Hazzah! Man, sometimes it is the simplest things!